# Update color of animated view after animation

Tags: react-native, animation, react-animated

I am creating a react native application and want to change the background color of an animated View after the user touches it. For more context, the view is in the shape of a square and I am rotating it 225 degrees when the component mounts. If the user touches the square, it will animate a flipping motion and show the other side of the square, which is a different color. The code I am using to do this can be seen below:

```
const app = (props) => {
   let colors = [color1, color2, color3, ...];
   let index = 0;
   let animatedValue= new Animated.Value(0);
   let squareSpin = new Animated.Value(0);
   let val = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(squareSpin, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 3000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();
  }, []);

  const startSpin = squareSpin.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ["0deg", "225deg"],
  });

  animatedValue.addListener(({ value }) => {
    val = value;
  });

  let frontInt= animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 180],
    outputRange: ["0deg", "180deg"],
  });

  let backInt = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 180],
    outputRange: ["180deg", "360deg"],
  });

  let opacityFront = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [89, 90],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });


  let opacityBack = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [89, 90],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
  });

  const flip= () => {
    if (val>= 90) {
      Animated.spring(animatedValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        friction: 6,
        tension: 8,
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.spring(animatedValue, {
        toValue: 180,
        friction: 6,
        tension: 8,
      }).start();
    }
  };

  const frontAnimated = {
    transform: [{ rotateY: frontInt }],
  };
  const backAnimated = {
    transform: [{ rotateY: backInt}],
  };

  return (
     <Animated.View
        style={{transform: [{ rotate: startSpin }] }}
      >
         <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => {
                index++;
                flip();
              }}>
            <Animated.View
                style={[
                  styles.shape,
                  {
                    backgroundColor:
                      colors[index % colors.length],
                  },
                  frontAnimated ,
                  { opacity: opacityFront },
                ]}
              >
              </Animated.View>
              <Animated.View
                style={[
                  styles.shape,
                  {
                    backgroundColor:
                      colors[(index + 1) % colors.length],
                  },
                  { position: "absolute" },
                  backAnimated ,
                  { opacity: opacityBack },
                ]}
              ></Animated.View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     <Animated.View>
  )

}
```

**The Problem**: The animations all work great, but the issue is that each side of the square I am flipping can only take on one color. Notice how in the `colors` array, there are multiple colors that the square should be based on the number of times the user presses the square. However, this is not happening and each side of the square is always the color is started out to be (color1 for the top side of the square and color2 for the bottom side of the square). I think this is happening because the `view` does not realize that the index is changing because it is never rendered again. Or maybe it simply cannot chance its color due to some properties of `Animated.View`, I am not really sure. I tried forcing a render when the square is pressed using `useState` but that resulted in the square to undo its rotation that happened when the component was mounted, which I do not want to happen. How do I get the background color of the views to change based on the number of taps by the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using two different color interpolation values.

```js
let colorSideOne = colorValue1.interpolate({
  inputRange: [...Array(colors.length)].map((_, index) => index),
  outputRange: colors,
});
let colorSideTwo = colorValue2.interpolate({
  inputRange: [...Array(colors.length)].map((_, index) => index),
  outputRange: colors,
});
```

and with these values set color to the background of the card

```js
<Animated.View
  style={[
    styles.shape,
    {
      backgroundColor: colorSideOne,
    },
    frontAnimated,
    { opacity: opacityFront },
  ]}>
</Animated.View>
<Animated.View
  style={[
    styles.shape,
    {
      backgroundColor: colorSideTwo,
    },
    frontAnimated,
    { opacity: opacityFront },
  ]}>
</Animated.View>
```

You now need to just properly update the colorValues depending on the index.

Note that you need to do this alternately for the front and back values

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  style={{
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'red',
  }}
  onPress={() => {
    index++;
    //side = side === 'front' ? 'back' : 'front';
    //console.log('side',side);
    // console.log('index',index, 'color length', colors.length);
    if (index & 1) {
      colorValue1.setValue((index + 1) % colors.length);
    } else {
      colorValue2.setValue((index + 1) % colors.length);
    }
    // console.log('color value', colorValue1, colorValue2);
    flip();
  }}>
    ....
    ....
```

For the clarity iam attaching this expo [demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/flip-card-with-colors)

Hope it is what you are expecting !

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is very close to what I am looking for. I implemented this and it seems that when you tap the square, the color that is currently on top (so color1 at the beginning) is changing colors to its next appropriate color (so color3 on the first tap) before the square is fully flipped. So the color changes and then the square is flipped, which looks a little odd. Is there a way to change the color of the top facing square only after the square has been flipped so that the user cant see it change?

Comment: I tried adding a setTimeout function around the if, else statement inside the onPress function but then if the user touches the color too fast, it begins to change color late.

Comment: you could try moving the color updation logic to be executed at end of Animated.spring callback.I tried that it is slightly better than before,but a portion of the color is still visible before completely flipped.May be try to handle with opacity somehow.

Comment: Hmmmm. Why does putting it in the callback not work? Since the callback is executed after the animation is done so the user should not be able to see the color update as the animation is still happening.

Comment: Yeah i too had the same question..see if it is ok for you.

Comment: Yea I tried to put it in the callback, it does not seem to work :/. Does it have something to do with the duration of the flip?

Comment: I put a `console.log` statement inside the callback and it is executing one second after the square is first pressed. So the color should not be changing during that time frame. It is odd that it is changing colors before the flip is finished.

Comment: Honestly i too am curious and want to know why it is happening that way but it's better if you ask for a separate question,if this answer satisfies the scope of the question it's better we stop the lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Inside render method

```
const BackgroundColorConfig = this.Animation.interpolate(
            {
                inputRange: [ 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1 ],
                
                outputRange: [ '#f6f6f6', '#f6f6f6', '#f6f6f6', LIGHT_RED_COLOR, LIGHT_RED_COLOR, LIGHT_RED_COLOR ]
     
            });


usage backgroundColor:BackgroundColorConfig
```

give above attribute to your component(it should be under Animated.View tag)

Make a function to call Animation and use it either on componentDidMount or on button click

```
Define this.Animated = new Animated.value(0)
```

in constructor

```
StartBackgroundColorAnimation = (value) =>
{
    Animated.timing(
        this.Animation,
        {
            toValue: value,
            duration: 600
        }
    ).start();
}
```